# How to comment out a line in all files?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a particular line in hundreds of files which has to be commented out. What command is appropriate ?

The line looks like:

```
       include $DIR/make/makefile.am
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's~^[[:blank:]]*include \$DIR/make/makefile\.am~#&~' file
```

Answer (score 2):

you can run the command suggested by anubhava in a find, if you want to run this on hundreds of files.

```
find <dir> -type f -name makefile.am -exec sed -i.bak 's~^[[:blank:]]*include \$DIR/make/makefile\.am~#&~' {} \;
```

where  is the base directory under which you want to recursively search makefile.am and comment out the include statement.

Hope it helps you.

You can further tweak the command according to your need.

Comment: If you want to run it on hundreds of files, it may be a good idea to replace `... {} \;` with `... {} +`. This way you will invoke sed with multiple files as arguments each time, and the execution time should be much smaller.